# I am getting started with Corda5, when I execute the command "./gradlew runPartyAServer", throws SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, corda

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cc-dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.1/84692d456bcce689355d33d68167875e486954dd/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cc-dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/home/cc-dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.1/84692d456bcce689355d33d68167875e486954dd/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:637)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:537)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:274)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:99)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:191)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:170)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at net.corda.samples.example.webserver.Starter.main(Starter.java:21)

```
//gradle file
buildscript {//properties that you need to build the project
    Properties constants = new Properties()
    file("$projectDir/../constants.properties").withInputStream { constants.load(it) }

    ext {
        corda_release_group = constants.getProperty("cordaReleaseGroup")
        corda_core_release_group =  constants.getProperty("cordaCoreReleaseGroup")
        corda_release_version = constants.getProperty("cordaVersion")
        corda_core_release_version = constants.getProperty("cordaCoreVersion")
        corda_gradle_plugins_version = constants.getProperty("gradlePluginsVersion")
        kotlin_version = constants.getProperty("kotlinVersion")
        junit_version = constants.getProperty("junitVersion")
        quasar_version = constants.getProperty("quasarVersion")
        log4j_version = constants.getProperty("log4jVersion")
        slf4j_version = constants.getProperty("slf4jVersion")
        corda_platform_version = constants.getProperty("platformVersion").toInteger()
        //springboot
        spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {//Properties that you need to compile your project (The application)
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/repositories.gradle"
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" // Required by Corda's serialisation framework.
    }

    jar {
        // This makes the JAR's SHA-256 hash repeatable.
        preserveFileTimestamps = false
        reproducibleFileOrder = true
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir rootProject.file("config/dev")
        }
    }
}
//Module dependencies
dependencies {
    // Corda dependencies.
    cordaCompile "$corda_core_release_group:corda-core:$corda_core_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies.
    cordapp project(":workflows")
    cordapp project(":contracts")

    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"
    cordaDriver "net.corda:corda-shell:4.10"

}

//Task to deploy the nodes in order to bootstrap a network
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {

    /* This property will load the CorDapps to each of the node by default, including the Notary. You can find them
     * in the cordapps folder of the node at build/nodes/Notary/cordapps. However, the notary doesn't really understand
     * the notion of cordapps. In production, Notary does not need cordapps as well. This is just a short cut to load
     * the Corda network bootstrapper.
     */
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
        runSchemaMigration = true //This configuration is for any CorDapps with custom schema, We will leave this as true to avoid
        //problems for developers who are not familiar with Corda. If you are not using custom schemas, you can change
        //it to false for quicker project compiling time.
    }
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}
```